# Scala Slick, Trouble with inserting Unicode into database

Tags: scala, slick

When I create a new row of data that contains several columns that may contain Unicode, the columns that do contain Unicode are being corrupted.

However, if I insert that data directly, using the mysql-cli Slick will retrieve that Unicode data fine.

Is there anything I should add to my table class to tell Slick that this Column may be a Unicode string?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, I have to set the character encoding, for the connection.

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/your_db_name?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to configure that on the db schema side by setting the right collation.